# Rails not using digested assets in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 4.2 app which is running with precompiled assets on Heroku.  We are trying to move to new platform ([Aptible](https://www.aptible.com)), but using the same settings, our app does not get the assets correctly anymore.  Yes, I ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to precompile the assets and verified they were available.

I had the server print out a few values

```
- puts Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.css').digest_path
- puts stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
```

and it has the right value for the asset, but the stylesheet_link_tag generates the wrong link.

```
[web0] application-2c5efa873b0d0254861e6a7ee25995dd.css
[web0] <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://<something>.cloudfront.net/stylesheets/application.css" />
```

Obviously there is something that is different when we are running on Heroku, but the config files are set up the same, as are the gems, etc. Here is the relevant portion of our staging.rb config file

```
App::Application.configure do    
  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=2592000'

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false)
  config.assets.compile = false # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.digest = true # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.version = '2.0' # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://<something>.cloudfront.net'
end
```

I searched online, but the only suggestion I found was to set 
   `config.assets.compile = true`, which does fix the problem, but also causes the server to time out trying to load pages after a deploy.

Does anyone know what is wrong here? Why is it looking for the non-digest assets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to run the precompile task on production after deployment.

I am under assumption that Heroku does this by default.

There are a few examples found here:

https://gist.github.com/fancyremarker/9652688

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but we are already doing that in our before_release tasks as suggested here https://support.aptible.com/topics/paas/how-to-store-static-assets/

Comment: Turns out the aptible support article was wrong and I did need to do the precompile assets command in the Dockerfile instead to make sure it happened inside the same container.